# This site can’t be reached during cypress configuration

Tags: cypress

I am a newbie to cypress and trying to install cypress on my local machine but while doing configuration through UI I am getting the below issue. I already use the below command to install cypress:

```
npm install cypress --save-dev
```

Step 1: Select chrome browser and click start E2E testing in Chrome
[image]

Sep 2: Getting the below issue after launching the chrome browser
[image]

Log:

```
cypress:launcher:browsers launching browser { browser: { name: 'chrome', family: 'chromium', channel: 'stable', displayName: 'Chrome', version: '108.0.5359.98', path: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe', minSupportedVersion: 64, majorVersion: '108', isHeaded: true, isHeadless: false }, url: 'about:blank' } +0ms
  cypress:launcher:browsers spawning browser with args { args: [ 'about:blank', '--test-type', '--ignore-certificate-errors', '--start-maximized', '--silent-debugger-extension-api', '--no-default-browser-check', '--no-first-run', '--noerrdialogs', '--enable-fixed-layout', '--disable-popup-blocking', '--disable-password-generation', '--disable-single-click-autofill', '--disable-prompt-on-repos', '--disable-background-timer-throttling', '--disable-renderer-backgrounding', '--disable-renderer-throttling', '--disable-backgrounding-occluded-windows', '--disable-restore-session-state', '--disable-new-profile-management', '--disable-new-avatar-menu', '--allow-insecure-localhost', '--reduce-security-for-testing', '--enable-automation', '--disable-print-preview', '--disable-device-discovery-notifications', '--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required', '--disable-site-isolation-trials', '--metrics-recording-only', '--disable-prompt-on-repost', '--disable-hang-monitor', '--disable-sync', '--disable-web-resources', '--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection', '--disable-client-side-phishing-detection', '--disable-component-update', "--simulate-outdated-no-au='Tue, 31 Dec 2099 23:59:59 GMT'", '--disable-default-apps', '--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream', '--use-fake-device-for-media-stream', '--disable-ipc-flooding-protection', '--disable-backgrounding-occluded-window', '--disable-breakpad', '--password-store=basic', '--use-mock-keychain', '--disable-dev-shm-usage', '--proxy-server=http://localhost:58163', '--proxy-bypass-list=<-loopback>', '--remote-debugging-port=58175', '--remote-debugging-address=127.0.0.1', '--load-extension=C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\AppData\\Roaming\\Cypress\\cy\\production\\browsers\\chrome-stable\\interactive\\CypressExtension,C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\AppData\\Local\\Cypress\\Cache\\12.0.1\\Cypress\\resources\\app\\packages\\extension\\theme', '--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\AppData\\Roaming\\Cypress\\cy\\production\\browsers\\chrome-stable\\interactive', '--disk-cache-dir=C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\AppData\\Roaming\\Cypress\\cy\\production\\browsers\\chrome-stable\\interactive\\CypressCache' ] } +0ms
  cypress:launcher:browsers spawning browser with environment { env: { ALLUSERSPROFILE: 'C:\\ProgramData', APPDATA: 'C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\AppData\\Roaming', BPPDOMAIN_MANAGER_ASM: 'EdrDotNet, Version=56.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=da1b3922653ea916', BPPDOMAIN_MANAGER_TYPE: 'EdrDotNet.EdrAppDomainManager', COLOR: '1', CommonProgramFiles: 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files', 'CommonProgramFiles(x86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files', CommonProgramW6432: 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files', COMPUTERNAME: 'UKC-DSEV023991', ComSpec: 'C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\cmd.exe', CYPRESS: 'true', CYPRESS_INTERNAL_ENV: 'production', DEBUG: 'cypress:*', DEBUG_COLORS: '1', DriverData: 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\DriverData', EDITOR: 'notepad.exe', FORCE_COLOR: '1', FORCE_STDERR_TTY: '1', FORCE_STDIN_TTY: '1', FORCE_STDOUT_TTY: '1', FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING: 'Internet Explorer', FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING: 'Default', GRADLE: 'C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\Downloads\\gradle-6.9.1-bin\\gradle-6.9.1\\bin', HOME: 'C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav', HOMEDRIVE: 'C:', HOMEPATH: '\\Users\\dipak.bachhav', INIT_CWD: 'C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\CypressFramework', 'IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition': 'C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\AppData\\Local\\JetBrains\\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.2\\bin;', JAVA_HOME: 'C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_281', LOCALAPPDATA: 'C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\AppData\\Local', LOGONSERVER: '\\\\UKC-DSEV023991', MAVEN_HOME: 'C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\Downloads\\apache-maven-3.8.4\\bin', MOCHA_COLORS: '1', NODE: 'C:\\Tools\\nodejs\\node.exe', NODE_EXE: 'C:\\Tools\\nodejs\\\\node.exe', NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED: '0', NO_PROXY: '127.0.0.1,::1,localhost', NPM_CLI_JS: 'C:\\Tools\\nodejs\\\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js', npm_command: 'exec', npm_config_cache: 'C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\AppData\\Local\\npm-cache', npm_config_globalconfig: 'C:\\Tools\\nodejs\\etc\\npmrc', npm_config_global_prefix: 'C:\\Tools\\nodejs', npm_config_init_module: 'C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\.npm-init.js', npm_config_legacy_peer_deps: 'true', npm_config_local_prefix: 'C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\CypressFramework', npm_config_metrics_registry: 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', npm_config_node_gyp: 'C:\\Tools\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js', npm_config_noproxy: '', npm_config_prefix: 'C:\\Tools\\nodejs', npm_config_userconfig: 'C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\.npmrc', npm_config_user_agent: 'npm/8.19.2 node/v18.12.1 win32 x64 workspaces/false', npm_execpath: 'C:\\Tools\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npx-cli.js', npm_lifecycle_event: 'npx', npm_lifecycle_script: 'cypress', npm_node_execpath: 'C:\\Tools\\nodejs\\node.exe', npm_package_json: 'C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\CypressFramework\\package.json', npm_package_name: 'cypressframework', npm_package_version: '1.0.0', NPM_PREFIX_NPX_CLI_JS: 'C:\\Tools\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npx-cli.js', NPX_CLI_JS: 'C:\\Tools\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npx-cli.js', NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS: '4', OneDrive: 'C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\OneDrive - Specsavers', OneDriveCommercial: 'C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\OneDrive - Specsavers', ORIGINAL_NODE_OPTIONS: ' --openssl-legacy-provider', ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP: 'undefined', OS: 'Windows_NT', Path: 'C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\CypressFramework\\node_modules\\.bin;C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\CypressFramework\\node_modules\\.bin;C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\node_modules\\.bin;C:\\Users\\node_modules\\.bin;C:\\node_modules\\.bin;C:\\Tools\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\@npmcli\\run-script\\lib\\node-gyp-bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files\\Oracle\\Java\\javapath;C:\\windows\\system32;C:\\windows;C:\\windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;C:\\windows\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Program Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Scripts;C:\\Program Files\\Amazon\\AWSCLIV2\\;%SystemRoot%\\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\\System32\\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\;%SYSTEMROOT%\\System32\\OpenSSH\\;C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\AppData\\Local\\JetBrains\\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1.2\\bin;;C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.8.0_281;C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\Downloads\\mongodb-windows-x86_64-5.0.2\\mongodb-win32-x86_64-windows-5.0.2\\bin;C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\Downloads\\gradle-6.9.1-bin\\gradle-6.9.1\\bin;C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\Downloads\\apache-maven-3.8.4\\bin;C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310;C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python310\\Scripts;C:\\Tools\\nodejs;;C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Microsoft VS Code\\bin', PATHEXT: '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC', PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE: 'AMD64', PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER: 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 78 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel', PROCESSOR_LEVEL: '6', PROCESSOR_REVISION: '4e03', ProgramData: 'C:\\ProgramData', ProgramFiles: 'C:\\Program Files', 'ProgramFiles(x86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)', ProgramW6432: 'C:\\Program Files', PROJECT_BASE_DIR: 'C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\AppData\\Local\\Cypress\\Cache\\12.0.1\\Cypress\\resources\\app', PROMPT: '$P$G', PSModulePath: 'C:\\Program Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules', PUBLIC: 'C:\\Users\\Public', SESSIONNAME: 'Console', snow_agent: 'C:\\Program Files\\Snow Software\\Inventory\\Agent', SystemDrive: 'C:', SystemRoot: 'C:\\WINDOWS', TEMP: 'C:\\Users\\DIPAK~1.BAC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp', TMP: 'C:\\Users\\DIPAK~1.BAC\\AppData\\Local\\Temp', USERDNSDOMAIN: 'ad.Specsavers.com', USERDOMAIN: 'ROOT', USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE: 'ROOT', USERNAME: 'dipak.bachhav', USERPROFILE: 'C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav', UV_THREADPOOL_SIZE: '128', windir: 'C:\\WINDOWS' } } +2ms
  cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 0, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:58175     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) { errno: -4078, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 58175 } } +20s
  cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 1, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:58175     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) { errno: -4078, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 58175 } } +103ms
  cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 2, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:58175     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) { errno: -4078, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 58175 } } +108ms
  cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 3, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:58175     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) { errno: -4078, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 58175 } } +116ms
  cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 4, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:58175     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) { errno: -4078, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 58175 } } +112ms
  cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 5, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:58175     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) { errno: -4078, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 58175 } } +132ms
  cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 6, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:58175     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) { errno: -4078, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 58175 } } +135ms
  cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 7, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:58175     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) { errno: -4078, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 58175 } } +125ms
  cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 8, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:58175     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) { errno: -4078, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 58175 } } +113ms
  cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 9, delay: 100, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:58175     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) { errno: -4078, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 58175 } } +113ms
  cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 10, delay: 500, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:58175     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) { errno: -4078, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 58175 } } +112ms
  cypress:network:connect received error on connect, retrying { iteration: 11, delay: 500, err: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:58175     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1187:16) { errno: -4078, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 58175 } } +551ms
  cypress:launcher:browsers chrome stderr: DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:58175/devtools/browser/7e36c6be-5f03-448f-b778-3bb16a60f1c9 +2s
  cypress:network:connect successfully connected { opts: { host: '127.0.0.1', port: 58175, getDelayMsForRetry: [Function: getDelayMsForRetry] }, iteration: 12 } +516ms
  cypress:server:browsers:cri-client connecting { target: 'ws://127.0.0.1:58175/devtools/browser/7e36c6be-5f03-448f-b778-3bb16a60f1c9' } +0ms
  cypress:server:browsers:browser-cri-client Attaching to target url about:blank +0ms
  cypress:server:browsers:cri-client connecting { target: '8FF8DFB3A6DAD300EF9853759F387E8B' } +150ms
  cypress:server:browsers:cri-client registering CDP on event { eventName: 'Inspector.targetCrashed' } +13ms
  cypress:server:browsers:chrome attaching listeners to chrome { url: 'http://localhost:58163/__/', options: { browser: { name: 'chrome', family: 'chromium', channel: 'stable', displayName: 'Chrome', version: '108.0.5359.98', path: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe', minSupportedVersion: 64, majorVersion: '108', isHeaded: true, isHeadless: false }, url: 'http://localhost:58163/__/', browsers: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ], userAgent: null, proxyUrl: 'http://localhost:58163', proxyServer: 'http://localhost:58163', socketIoRoute: '/__socket', chromeWebSecurity: true, isTextTerminal: false, downloadsFolder: 'C:\\Users\\dipak.bachhav\\CypressFramework\\cypress\\downloads', experimentalModifyObstructiveThirdPartyCode: false, experimentalWebKitSupport: false, onBrowserClose: [Function (anonymous)], onError: [Function: onError], relaunchBrowser: [AsyncFunction (anonymous)], onBrowserOpen: [Function: onBrowserOpen] } } +3s
  cypress:server:browsers:cri-client registering CDP on event { eventName: 'Network.requestWillBeSent' } +1ms
  cypress:server:browsers:cri-client registering CDP on event { eventName: 'Network.responseReceived' } +1ms
  cypress:launcher:browsers chrome stderr: [9984:11536:1208/135124.795:ERROR:scoped_file_writer.cc(16)] Could not open pak file for writing: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. (0x20) +828ms
  cypress:server:browsers:cri-client registering CDP on event { eventName: 'Page.downloadWillBegin' } +441ms
  cypress:server:browsers:cri-client registering CDP on event { eventName: 'Page.downloadProgress' } +0ms
  cypress:server:browsers:chrome received CRI client +450ms
  cypress:server:browsers:chrome navigating to page http://localhost:58163/__/ +0ms
  cypress:server:browsers:cri-client registering CDP on event { eventName: 'Fetch.requestPaused' } +572ms
  cypress:server:browsers:chrome listen for frame tree changes +565ms
  cypress:server:browsers:cri-client registering CDP on event { eventName: 'Page.frameAttached' } +1ms
  cypress:server:browsers:cri-client registering CDP on event { eventName: 'Page.frameDetached' } +0ms
  cypress:server:browsers browser opened +4s
  cypress:launcher:browsers chrome stderr: [9984:9040:1208/135128.366:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [13:51:28.372] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1045 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F) +4s
  cypress:launcher:browsers chrome stderr: [9984:9040:1208/135128.377:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [13:51:28.377] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1045 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
[9984:9040:1208/135128.377:ERROR:device_event_log_impl.cc(215)] [13:51:28.377] USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1045 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F) +5ms
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler current & mean memory and CPU usage by process group:
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler ┌─────────┬───────────┬──────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬──────────────┬─────────────┐
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler │ (index) │   group   │ processCount │                          pids                           │ cpuPercent │ meanCpuPercent │ memRssMb │ meanMemRssMb │ maxMemRssMb │
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler ├─────────┼───────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┤
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler │    0    │ 'Chrome'  │      8       │ '9984, 8772, 6004, 13368, 9076, 15556 ... 2 more items' │    0.07    │      0.07      │  372.75  │    372.75    │   372.75    │
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler │    1    │ 'cypress' │      1       │                         '8648'                          │    3.31    │      6.86      │  330.57  │    296.42    │   330.57    │
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler │    2    │  'other'  │      6       │        '6688, 17712, 10992, 13048, 3460, 17504'         │    3.48    │      2.96      │  241.91  │    206.43    │   262.01    │
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler │    3    │ 'plugin'  │      2       │                      '9872, 10916'                      │     0      │      0.16      │  80.52   │     79.6     │    80.52    │
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler │    4    │  'TOTAL'  │      17      │                           '-'                           │    6.86    │      9.96      │ 1025.75  │    655.74    │   1025.75   │
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler └─────────┴───────────┴──────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴──────────────┴─────────────┘ +11s
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler current & mean memory and CPU usage by process group:
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler ┌─────────┬───────────┬──────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬──────────────┬─────────────┐
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler │ (index) │   group   │ processCount │                          pids                           │ cpuPercent │ meanCpuPercent │ memRssMb │ meanMemRssMb │ maxMemRssMb │
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler ├─────────┼───────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┤
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler │    0    │ 'Chrome'  │      8       │ '9984, 8772, 6004, 13368, 9076, 15556 ... 2 more items' │    4.68    │      2.37      │  384.62  │    378.68    │   384.62    │
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler │    1    │ 'cypress' │      1       │                         '8648'                          │    1.56    │      5.8       │  325.21  │    302.18    │   330.57    │
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler │    2    │  'other'  │      6       │         '6688, 17712, 10992, 1488, 16900, 2224'         │    0.82    │      2.53      │  209.05  │    206.95    │   262.01    │
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler │    3    │ 'plugin'  │      2       │                      '9872, 10916'                      │     0      │      0.12      │  80.52   │    79.83     │    80.52    │
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler │    4    │  'TOTAL'  │      17      │                           '-'                           │    7.06    │      9.38      │  999.39  │    724.47    │   1025.75   │
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler └─────────┴───────────┴──────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴──────────────┴─────────────┘ +11s
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler current & mean memory and CPU usage by process group:
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler ┌─────────┬───────────┬──────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬──────────────┬─────────────┐
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler │ (index) │   group   │ processCount │                          pids                           │ cpuPercent │ meanCpuPercent │ memRssMb │ meanMemRssMb │ maxMemRssMb │
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler ├─────────┼───────────┼──────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼────────────┼────────────────┼──────────┼──────────────┼─────────────┤
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler │    0    │ 'Chrome'  │      7       │ '9984, 8772, 6004, 13368, 9076, 15556 ... 1 more items' │   -0.28    │      1.49      │  364.69  │    374.02    │   384.62    │
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler │    1    │ 'cypress' │      1       │                         '8648'                          │   -0.16    │      4.81      │  313.13  │     304      │   330.57    │
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler │    2    │  'other'  │      6       │         '6688, 17712, 10992, 4500, 9404, 10956'         │     0      │      2.11      │  207.4   │    207.03    │   262.01    │
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler │    3    │ 'plugin'  │      2       │                      '9872, 10916'                      │   -0.07    │      0.08      │  64.07   │    76.68     │    80.52    │
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler │    4    │  'TOTAL'  │      16      │                           '-'                           │    -0.5    │      7.73      │  949.29  │    761.94    │   1025.75   │
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler └─────────┴───────────┴──────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴──────────────┴─────────────┘ +11s
  cypress:data-context:sources:GitDataSource Refreshing git data +48s
  cypress:data-context:sources:GitDataSource getting git info for [ 'C:/Users/dipak.bachhav/CypressFramework/cypress/e2e/search.feature' ]: +203ms
  cypress:data-context:sources:GitDataSource executing command: `FOR %x in ("C:\Users\dipak.bachhav\CypressFramework\cypress\e2e\search.feature") DO (git log --max-count=1 --pretty="format:%ci %ar %an|%h|%s" %x)` +0ms
  cypress:data-context:sources:GitDataSource cwd: `C:\Users\dipak.bachhav\CypressFramework` +0ms
  cypress:data-context:sources:GitDataSource On current branch  +337ms
  cypress:server:util:process_profiler current & mean memory and CPU usage by process group:
```

Comment: is the cypress binary missing?

Comment: nope its present

Comment: have you tried yarn yet? If not try yarn sometimes node produces bugs with --save-dev

Comment: how it's adding more value if behavior is on a intermittent basis

Comment: stackoverflow is not providing me with images idk why so I have no idea about the issue. I can only say from my experience with cypress